# using conditionalPanel with values from checkboxGroupInput

Tags: r, shiny

I want to use checkboxGroupInput and then, if a certain box is checked, i want a conditionalPanel. A toy example is here:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage( 

 sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput("items","Which Item?",
          choices=c("A","B","C","D")),
        conditionalPanel( condition = "input.items == 'D'",       
          numericInput("n","n",value=50,min=0,max=100,step=1)
        )
      ),       
      mainPanel(
      uiOutput("text")
     )
 )
```

))

now this works fine if only box 'D' is selected, but not if (as would be normal in my problem) several boxes are selected.

in server.R something like

```
 if("D" %in% input$which)
```

works fine but that does not seem to work in ui.R. I also tried subsetting ala R, for example

```
  conditionalPanel( condition = "input.items[4] == 'D'",
```

but that does not work either.

Wolfgang

Comment: You have to use javascript code inside the condition, so you can't use R-syntax. Try `conditionalPanel(condition = "input.items.includes('D')"`)

Comment: Thanks docendo! that works perfectly. I was suspecting something along those lines and searched for what is the correct syntax, but without success. Also, i am not familiar with javascript. Is there some place where i could go to learn more?

Comment: No I can't tell you a good place. I had the same problem and figured it out somehow. But I'm not familiar with JavaScript either, in general.

Comment: @docendodiscimus 's answer oddly did not work in my case, but Winston Chang's answer at the bottom of this thread did: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/nbFGlNTcK_s

Comment: Any reason why includes is required rather than an "in" statement? Passing reactive %in% results from R also did not work. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in

Answer (score 14, accepted):

docendo gave the correct answer: the syntax is

```
  conditionalPanel(condition = "input.items.includes('D')"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

somehow it no longer works with shiny v1.1.0. I am using R version 3.5.1 with platform windows. Rather than the `includes()` solution, the below works well for me (just in case others encounter the same issue):

`conditionalPanel(condition = "input.items.indexOf('D') > -1", ...)`

Comment: The solution below still works with Shiny version 1.2.0