# conditionalPanel() based on includes logic from string

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, conditional-statements

My inquiry feels close to [this inqury](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35688394/using-conditionalpanel-with-values-from-checkboxgroupinput/52556003#52556003), but the support provided is limited to the logic being applied to one data element.

I would like to learn the JavaScript to apply to a string/ vector/ array (not sure which language to use for my example) such that if any mammal were selected, the message would appear, but if any bird were select, the message would no appear.

```
library(shiny)

birds <- c("finch","robin","crow","duck")
mammals <- c("elephant", "human", "dog", 'cat')

ui <- fluidPage(
   titlePanel("Select Conditional"),
     mainPanel(
       column(4,
       selectizeInput(inputId = "animals",
                      label = "Select An Animal",
                      choices= list('Examples of Birds' = birds, 
                                    'Example of mammals' = mammals)
       )),
       column(8,
       conditionalPanel(condition = "input.animals.indexOf('birds')",
       textOutput("text")))
     ))

server <- function(input, output) {
      output$text <- renderText({"This is a mammal."})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I have attempted

```
conditionalPanel(condition = "input.animals.Array.indexOf('birds')",

conditionalPanel(condition = "input.animals.str.indexOf('birds')"

conditionalPanel(condition = "input.animals.Vector.indexOf('birds')"

conditionalPanel(condition = "input.animals.String.indexOf('birds')"
```

Thanks for any ideas. Please excused my lack of knowledge about vectors, arrays, strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-input variables in R doesn't get passed to JavaScript, as a workaround, I built the character vector into a JS array and passed that inside the condition.
So, the actual condition passed in this case is `['elephant', 'human', 'dog', 'cat'].includes(input.animals)` which does what you wanted.

```
library(shiny)

birds <- c("finch","robin","crow","duck")
mammals <- c("elephant", "human", "dog", 'cat')

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Select Conditional"),
  mainPanel(
    column(4,
           selectizeInput(inputId = "animals",
                          label = "Select An Animal",
                          choices= list('Examples of Birds' = birds, 
                                        'Example of mammals' = mammals)
           )),
    column(8,
           conditionalPanel(condition = paste0(paste0("[",toString(paste0("'",mammals,"'")),"]"),".includes(input.animals)"),
                            textOutput("text")))
  ))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$text <- renderText({"This is a mammal."})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you for quick and informative response. This works when I run condition = paste0(paste0("[",toString(paste0("'",birds,"'")),"]"),".indexOf(input.animals)", but not with .includes

Comment: This may be a browser issue since `includes` is an ES6 command or it could be a shiny version issue, It works in Shiny v1.4.0 and R v3.6.1 with Chrome v81.0.4044.138. Anyways, glad I could help.

Comment: I did not realize that I had to view the app in the browser to fully see the impact of the conditional.